# How to get nth level of parsed json?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON that has three levels and it's stored as Array I need to get 2nd level(count started from 0) and below in each level has 10+ elements. How it can be implemented on JavaScript.Need your help. All response will be helpful.

ps. some 1st level and 2nd level elements can be empty

```
[
  {
    "name": "0th level first", //0th level
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "1st level Cafe", // 1st level
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "2nd level Staff", //2nd level
            "options": [
              {
                "name": "Gary", //3rd level
                "age": 18
              },
              {
                "name": "James", //3rd level
                "age": 25
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: json you provide is not valid

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski what's wrong with it?

Comment: provide how the output json (result you wan't to get) should look like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: can you provide your expected output

Comment: I just came up with a solution, that I wouldn't consider the best in terms of readability, and also support (it's experimental) but I just wanted to try out the `flatMap` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), which isn't a part of Node.JS for instance, so be careful of it's support across browsers: 

`arr.flatMap(firstLevel => firstLevel.options.flatMap(secondLevel => secondLevel.options.flatMap(finalLevel => finalLevel.options)));`

Comment: sorry, i did't write that some 1st level and 2nd level elements can be empty

Answer (score 0):

Assume `data` contains your json, we have 2 onliners:

```
let out = data[0].options[0].options[0];

let outArr = data.flatMap(x=>x.options.flatMap(y=>y.options));
```

results

```
// out = {"name":"2nd level Staff","options":[{"name":"Gary","age":18},{"name":"James","age":25}]}

// outArr = [{"name":"2nd level Staff","options":[{"name":"Gary","age":18},{"name":"James","age":25}]}]
```

First one (`out`) contains one 2nd element. We use here tree indexes here (three zeros) first `data[0]` return first element in array data, then `options[0]` return first element in options array.

The second solution (`outArr`) contains array of all 2nd elements. We use here [JS flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

To write second solution inspired me **abdullahkady** comment below question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this one? :)

```
  data.forEach((value, index) => {
    for(stage0 in value){
      if(typeof value[stage0] === 'object'){
        value[stage0].forEach((val, index) => {
          for(stage1 in val){
            if(typeof val[stage1] === 'object'){
              val[stage1].forEach((val2, index) => {
                for(stage2 in val2){
                  console.log(val2[stage2]);
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which will be only iterating through each level.

on first loop there is a property call options which is an array, you need to loop through the options array in 0 level, on the second loop again one more options array comes you need to again loop through the options array which is 1 level.
then you reach the thrid level which is your output.

Third level means starting from zero its second level.

I hope this will solve the issue.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "0th level first", //0th level
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "1st level Cafe", // 1st level
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "2nd level Staff", //2nd level
            "options": [
              {
                "name": "Gary", //3rd level
                "age": 18
              },
              {
                "name": "James", //3rd level
                "age": 25
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

data.forEach(fl => {
 fl.options.forEach(sl => {
  sl.options.forEach(tl => {
    console.log("second level starting from 0",tl)
  })
 })
})
```